# Add Custom behaviour attr to A View

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to write a custom behavior but android studio flags the custom attributes as missing i.e

attrs.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="VerticalDisplacement_Params">
    <attr name="custom_Attr" format="boolean" />
</declare-styleable>
```

layout.xml

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_behavior=".Behavior"
        app:custom_Attr="true">
```

custom_Attr is flagged as an invalid prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I plugged your custom element into a custom view I had made and it worked fine. Some things I would suggest:

1. Check that your `<declare-stylable>` is wrapped in a `<resources>` tag:

```
    <resources>
        <declare-styleable name="VerticalDisplacement_Params">
            <attr name="custom_Attr" format="boolean" />
        </declare-styleable>
    <resources>
```

2. That the `app` namespace is defined as `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
3. The `declare-styleable` needs to have the `name` of the component. If you're adding a new attribute to `ContraintLayout` - you'll have to extend the `ContraintLayout` class, but this did work for me:

```
    <declare-styleable name="ConstraintLayout">
        <attr name="custom_Attr" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

5. Your `attrs.xml` exists inside the `values` folder

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked perfect extending the ConstraintLayout, (or any other view) was what I was looking for...

Comment: Can you mark this as the answer if I answered your question?